# How to turn off "Weekly writing exercise chat" notification?

Tags: support, chat, notifications

"Weekly writing exercise chat" notification annoy me because I don't participate in it. How to turn off the notification?

Comment: About as trivial as something can be, hence the downvotes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think that's a logical downvote reason in this case. This is a normal support question.

Comment: @AnnaLear to get such notification, one must first subscribe to the event, so it's pretty obvious that's where he can also unsubscribe. But agree it's not such a horrible thing, thanks for being the voice of sanity. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Eh, that requires remembering that you've done so (possibly months ago), and navigating the chat interface. ;)

Comment: @Anna: and talking of remembering: I notice that there is no list of subscribed events on your profile page. E.g. Only going through all the rooms in the events tab can you discover what you are registered for. Outside the event reminder, of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You registered for a [chat event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/168/the-overlook-hotel?tab=schedule); simply *cancel your registration* to not get notified again:

[image]