# Getting constant event notifications in chat that I never registered for

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, chat, chat-event

A couple of weeks ago I asked a question in Physics chat (the only time I ever went there) and was referred to the Pod Bay chat. I spoke briefly to someone in there and now when I'm in English Language & Usage chat I am constantly getting notifications of events in Pod Bay that are soon to occur.

[image: One of the offending notifications]

**I don't want to get these notifications. I did not register for anything. How do I turn them off?**

I looked at [How do I stop getting notifications for a chat event?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236932/144195), which tells you how to stop getting notifications you registered for. Again, I registered for *nothing*. So this does not apply.

**addendum**

The Pod Bay chat is not favorited by me, nor have I, to my knowledge, stated a preference for it in any other way. See below:

[image: How Pod Bay chat appears to me]

**more**

Now it's also happening for Physics, the other chat I visited *once*:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried registering and unregistering?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. I don't even know *how* to register. I just went and looked and it seems each event has a "Register" link next to it. Does that mean I would have to register for everything as it comes up and then unregister? Seems kinda cumbersome.

Comment: Maybe you've favorited [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay?tab=general) (the big star after the name - if it's yellow, you starred the room - then click it again to unstar)?

Comment: @nicael: Nice try and thanks for the thought, but as you can see (above image) that is not the case.

Comment: I am fairly certain this is by-design, you're getting the notifications because you visited The Pod Bay in the past X days (I think it's something like 7-14 days). The notifications will cease after that period

Comment: Ok, maybe you should "leave" those rooms?

Comment: @nicael: Can you describe how much more one has to do to "leave" those rooms beyond merely leaving them? They don't show up above the starboard on my regular EL&U chat, as they would if I were active in them.

Comment: [Try clicking "leave", below the room tags and participants](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IELtw.png)

Comment: You mean enter the room again to leave it? I don't understand. The info on that room has a button that says "join this room" which ought to mean I am not in it.

Comment: OK, I did that now (clicked "leave (all)") and then when I went back into ELU chat it showed that I was in the Trash room, where I had sent a few ELU chag messages recently, so I left that one using the up arrow link (a procedure I followed to "leave" the other chats after I saw them above the starboard once I'd physically left them. So we'll see if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: "join room" appears anyway, even if you're already in the room. It's just a link to the chat.

Comment: I've had this problem too. The only workaround for the time being is to not go back to either of those rooms for 3-7 days and the notifications should stop. Extremely annoying.

Comment: Did the notifications stop coming?

Comment: @nicael: No. Got one just now.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you take the advice of those who commented. Staying out of the chat room for some time [should eventually cause you to stop getting notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108485/let-users-opt-out-of-scheduled-event-notifications):

> So from now on, the definition of "room you're interested in" is as
>   follows:
>
> - Either you're in the room right now,
> - or you have ever spoken in this room, and at least one of these two is true:
>
>   - the last time you spoke here was less than 30 days ago, or
>   - the last time you were in the room was less than 7 days ago.

If they still keep coming in even after a month of not talking (and 7 days of not entering), create a bug report here and note that in your post.

Comment: Well, I've never gone back to those chats and it's getting close to a month now. And I thought the people who created this site check the [tag:bug] queue from time to time.

Comment: Are you still getting notifications?

Comment: Read the comment chain under the question, you'll see.

Comment: Have you asked the creators of this site network? They might have a solution.

Comment: +0 for an unsatisfying answer after a comment that shows it does not work

Comment: @mitch Hey, it's better than having no answer at all.

Comment: This *is* the correct answer. I've added a link and quote from an answer by one of the chat devs to back up the advice.

Comment: @Shog9 those notifications are quite intrusive, no chance to implement some "ignore" or "forget me" feature for a chat room? Personally I don't really need it, but OP here appears to use chat very often and do care a lot about this.

Comment: *I* use chat very often, @ShadowWizard. This isn't my favorite feature either, but honestly it's not that big of a deal unless someone's creating a *ton* of chat events. I'd support a "dismiss forever for this room" option that also prevented ever *registering* for a chat event in said room if someone cared to write up the feature-request. Still, there are a few things that'd probably come first on the TODO list of chat enhancements.

Comment: @Shog9: Perhaps a warning then on the chat placard before you click "enter"? Something like: "Warning, this chat sent out 29 event notifications over the last two days. You will get notifications at this rate for an unpredictable amount of time if you enter here *and you will not be able to prevent this*."

Comment: @Mitch: I interpret “it’s getting close to a month now” as less than a month, so it does *not* disprove the answer.